# Sea Quail Generated MySQL SQL Data causes #1064 SQL Error

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-error-1064

At the site Sea [Quail Database Diagram Tool](http://diagrams.seaquail.net/#) which is great for creating database diagrams I just created a MySQL database schema diagram - very basic one to get a feel of it.

I created the script to run from PHPMyadmin to add this all to a database created there to see if importing would work OK, but I ran into this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------' at line 2
```

Here is a snippet of the SQL data that was generated for me.

```
    -- Create Table: name_fields
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE name_fields
(
    `` VARCHAR(250)  NULL 
)
ENGINE=INNODB



-- Create Table: name_api
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE name_api
(
    `` VARCHAR(250)  NULL 
)
ENGINE=INNODB



-- Create Table: name_users
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE name_users
(
    `ID` BIGINT  NULL 
    ,`user_login` VARCHAR(250)  NULL 
    ,`user_name` VARCHAR(250)  NULL 
    ,`user_password` VARCHAR(250)  NULL 
)
ENGINE=INNODB



-- Create Table: name_options
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE name_options
(
    `` VARCHAR(250)  NULL 
)
ENGINE=INNODB



-- Create Table: name_ideal
```

Not sure what is wrong with the syntax here. Is there an easy way to debug this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have syntax error

First of all the

```
-- Create Table: name_fields
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Should be in one line you need to check this

something like

```
-- Create Table: name_fields  ------------------------------------------------------
```

2nd thing

```
CREATE TABLE name_fields
(
    `` VARCHAR(250)  NULL 
)
ENGINE=INNODB
```

Where is the column name ? you have just specified ``. The same is for name_api table too, correct these and it should work.

Comment: Yeah the `---` I needed to align and I needed column names for all tables. That was not even enough for PHPMyAdmin though, but from the command line I could run the table creation commands. For PHPMyAdmin I might needs back ticks for the table name and a semicolon at the end. Will check that at later time. Thanks